# Azure ADF unable to create linked service to an Azure SQL server VM in a different tenancy or subscription

Tags: azure-sql-database

I am trying to create a pipeline to copy some data between Azure SQL databases on different servers, but creating a Linked Service using SQL authentication fails (and gives no helpful information, just a dialog box saying it failed).  I think that the server VMs are in different tenancies or different subscriptions (I am not sure of the distinction), so I am guessing that the one I am working in cannot see the one I want the connection to go to.  Is that likely, and what needs to be done to make it work?  Any advice welcome, including RTFM if you can point me at the right one and it doesn't take weeks to wade through it!

Comment: What's youd database? You want to copy data from a single database to a managed instance, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone hits the same issue: the problem turned out to be the 'encrypted' checkbox in the self-hosted integration runtime (IR).  Clearing this flag allowed the IR to see the target database, and the pipeline could then be created with the new connection set to use that IR.  @Leon Yue: both databases are Azure SQL instances on Azure PaaS VMs.